# ChangeDisplaySettings only seems to work for primary monitor (returns DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE)

Tags: winapi, windows-10, screen-orientation, multiple-monitors, screen-rotation

I have two displays in my system: my laptop display and an external monitor. **Independent** from which is the primary screen, I would like to change the screen rotation. I started from the examples in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx and this is my simple test code:

```
DWORD displayNumber = 1;

DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
ZeroMemory(&dd, sizeof(dd));
dd.cb = sizeof(dd);

DEVMODE dm;
ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

if (0 != EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, displayNumber , &dd, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
{
    if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
    {
        // swap height and width
        DWORD dwTemp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
        dm.dmPelsWidth = dwTemp;

        // determine new orientaion
        switch (dm.dmDisplayOrientation)
        {
        case DMDO_DEFAULT:
            dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_270;
            break;
        case DMDO_270:
            dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180;
            break;
        case DMDO_180:
            dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90;
            break;
        case DMDO_90:
            dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_DEFAULT;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        long lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0);
        if (DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL != lRet)
        {
            switch (lRet)
            {
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_BADDUALVIEW"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_BADFLAGS"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_BADPARAM"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_FAILED:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_FAILED"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_NOTUPDATED"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("DISP_CHANGE_RESTART"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox(0, _T("default"), _T("ChangeDisplaySettings failed"), 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, the first display is the laptop display (and also the primary display) and the second display is external monitor.

If I execute the code above with `displayNumber = 0`, everything works as expected: The laptop screen rotates and the main screen stays as it is.

However, if I set `displayNumber = 1`, `ChangeDisplaySettings` returns `DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE`. It seems the rotation can only be changed for the primary display that way.

Contrary, if I set the external monitor to be the primary display, things work as expected for `displayNumber = 1`. However, with `displayNumber = 0`, the settings on the external monitor get all messed up while the laptop display (first display) rotates, as expected.

What's going on here?

Comment: As it fails both times when it's the external monitor, have you confirmed that the display driver for that monitor supports rotation changes?

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, it works with the settings and iRotate. However, I meanwhile found the solution. Seems `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` has to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I need to use `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` instead and explicitely specify the display device. I found a sample code on https://gist.github.com/umq/986635 that works.

Instead of

```
long lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0);
```

write:

```
long lRet = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(dd.DeviceName, &dm, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Done.

Comment: Can you [edit] this answer and post your working code solution as well? Answers that contain primarilly content on an off-site location aren't useful here. The relevant content should be here, so that it will be preserved here along with the question to make sure it stays available to others in the future. (Don't remove the attribution to the other site, though.)

Comment: And also remember to mark yourself if this does solve your issue, to help people with the same issue.